# Prompting user for download, IE sets the filename as the .aspx name ("Would you like to download SomePage.aspx?fileID=12345")

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am at a loss here.  I am trying to transmit a file on the local intranet site.  When I get a download prompt in IE11, it says:

> Do you want to open or save "SomePage.aspx?fileID=12345"?  [open] [save] [cancel]

Instead of..

> Do you want to open or save "Document.pdf"? [open] [save] [cancel]

It works perfectly fine on Chrome.  The file gets downloaded with the correct filename.  But for some reason, IE isn't setting the name and instead uses the ASPX name.

The code is rather straightforward:

```
testFile = New System.IO.FileInfo("\\someshare\somefolder$\Document.pdf")
Response.Clear()
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & testFile.Name)
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", testFile.Length.ToString())
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
Response.TransmitFile(testFile.FullName)
```

I've tried a number of different header options and the MIME type makes no difference.

Does anyone have a clue why this would be happening?

Notes: Not HTTPS.  It is not limited to PDF, same happens with .TIF, .DOC, and every other format I've tested.

**EDIT:** Have also tried `Response.WriteFile` as well as `Response.BinaryWrite` .. same thing each time.

**EDIT2:** Simplified everything down to a single button on a completely blank page.

[image]

Comment: Are you calling Response.Flush and Response.End after TransmitFile?

Comment: @Damon Tried, yes.  It prompts file download (with .aspx as filename) and then immediately throws an exception.  I have also tried `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()` as suggested elsewhere, as well as `Response.Close` for good measure. And as I said, this works without issue in Chrome ... IE is the only one having trouble.

Comment: Is this error only happening with your site? Or do you get this error when trying to download files from any random site using IE 11?

Comment: @msm8bball Other sites are fine.  I just now tried one from SourceForge to test, and it presented me with the correct filename.

Comment: How strange, the only thing that looks like it might cause a problem is the UNC path to the file, have you tried downloading a test file in your website?

Comment: @Damon Same thing with local file on the website.  Tried using `Server.MapPath("~/images/logo_large.png")` .. still presented me with `SomePage.aspx?fileID=12345` instead of `logo_large.png`

Comment: Since server-side .NET code often results in browser-side javascript... have you tried comparing the rendered code?  (In Chrome, right-click & "View page source";  In I.E., right-click & "View source".)

Answer (score 2):

You should have quote marks around the file name. See 19.5.1 on http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html
i.e.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fname.ext"
```

so...

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename=""{0}""", testFile.Name))
```

Unfortunately I have not been able to test if this solves your issue as I don't have access to IE11 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

So I know this question is older, but the solution I finally came up with to this problem is to add the following two lines to my code.

```
Response.SuppressContent = True
```

and

```
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
```

You have said in previous comments that you have tried the CompleteRequest command to no avail.

As a note, I am not 100% certain to the logistics of the Response.SuppressContent() command.

The documentation says that it indicates "whether to send HTTP content to the client". This seems counter intuitive to the process of sending the request body back to the client, however, it appears to only suppress the parts of the response that include any HTML.

It seems that the partial or incomplete HTML is what causes the filename to appear as the page name regardless of the headers set and sent. Stripping this out should cause the file to download properly.

Interestingly, this solution is actually born out of a secondary issue where once I was able to export the file using ClosedXML, i was receiving messages when opening the document that there were errors than excel would try to fix.

Response.SuppressContent actually fixed that as well. Hope this helps or at least points you in the right direction.